# How to resize an iBooks' book window after switching between display?

Tags: window-manager, books

I was reading a book on my MBP when it connects to two external monitors. I have make the book window fits the screen width.

However after I disconnected the monitors and tried to read the book on the MBP screen, it is what I see

[image]

The top part of the window is outside the viewport. The window allows me to resize but  there is no way I can move the window around. I tried to move the book window to a different desktop but the window stays in the same shape and form.

Because the top menu part if obstructed, I cannot even close the book window.

No option to close the window is available even after the book window is minimized.

[image]

How can I refit the window to the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to resize the book to its "original" size with  <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>. Usually the window gets very small then.

You can always close an open book with <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>.